# Change the bottom navigation screen and its index on button press

Tags: flutter

I am working on the bottom navigation bar feature. I have 4 screens associated with a bottom navigation bar.

- Page1 Index0 (It has a button)
- Page2 Index1
- Page3 Index2
- Page4 Index3

Each click on the bottom icon will change the index of a bottom navigation bar and triggers the specific screen to load.

Now I want to click on the button of screen 1 which is index 0 of a bottom navigation bar, this should make a call to load page2 as if I select the second icon of a bottom navigation bar.

I tried using the navigator.push(context,page()) which loaded the page however the bottom navigation bar was not visible. This is not the way, Is there any way to do it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You could set your screens in a PageView widget and controll it's navigation with your BottomNavigationBar buttons. Per say, you can make a function to navigate between pages when these buttons are pressed and, in your specific Use Case, the button of your screen one can call this function to navigate to the desired screen. PageView will group all your screens in one single space, so you won't have to worry about building the BottomNavigationBar again. Hope this works for you. If you don't like the PageView widget you can try also with an IndexedStack. It takes a list of widgets (screens) too.

Answer (score 1):

You can change bottom navigation bar index from every screen

```
static int bottomNavigationTabIndex = 0;
static void selectPage(BuildContext context,int index) {
    BottomNavigationScreenState? stateObject = context.findAncestorStateOfType<BottomNavigationScreenState>();
    stateObject?.setState((){
      bottomNavigationTabIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **IndexedStack** widget for this. Example is as follows:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0; //Current selected index of the bottom navigation bar tab

  void changeTab(int index) {
    setState(() => _currentIndex = index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //List of Screens that you want to put
    final screens = [
      const Screen1(),
      const Screen2(),
      const Screen3(),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentIndex,
        children: screens,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => changeTab(index),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        iconSize: 20,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.foo),
            label: 'Screen1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bar),
            label: 'Screen2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.baz),
            label: 'Screen3',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I don't use PageView, the page won't load. I am using a page controller to push the new page on the tap of a bottom navigation bar. I have a button widget inside the Screen1 widget. If I press the button widget I need to somehow call the initial changeTab function to push the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I've read your question and that's what I found out:
You want to change the bottom navigation bar pages by clicking on a button.

- To do so, simply change the index variable that you are passing to the selected index of the bottom navigation to the index of the page you want, and you will need to make it inside a setState function so the variable get updated.

Like the code below:

```
onTap: () {
  setState((() => this.index = 0));
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue using a Provider. The issue has been resolved now.